# Create a mock for a type in angular

Tags: angular, jasmine, angular-test

I was trying to create mock for type in .spec file and could not do that, can some one help me please on that..

component code is as follows

```
import {Component, Input, OnInit} from '@angular/core';
import {Applications} from '../model/applications';

@Component({
    selector: 'application',
    templateUrl: './application.html',
    styleUrls: ['./application.css']
})
export class Application implements OnInit {

    @Input() rowData: any;

    columnDefinition: any[];
    applications: Applications;

    constructor() {
    }

    ngOnInit() {
        this.columnDefinition = [
            {field: 'appName', header: 'Application Name', class: 'application-name-column'},
            {field: 'appVersion', header: 'Version', class: 'fenix-version-column'}
        ];
    }
}
```

and My spec is as follows.

```
import {async, ComponentFixture, TestBed} from '@angular/core/testing';

import {Application from './application.component';
import {TableModule} from 'primeng/table';
describe('ApplicationComponent', () => {
    let component: ApplicationComponent;
    let fixture: ComponentFixture<ApplicationComponent>;

    beforeEach(async(() => {
        TestBed.configureTestingModule({
            declarations: [ApplicationComponent],
            imports: [TableModule]
        })
            .compileComponents();
    }));

    beforeEach(() => {
        fixture = TestBed.createComponent(ApplicationComponent);
        component = fixture.componentInstance;
        fixture.detectChanges();
    });

    it('should create', () => {
        expect(component).toBeTruthy();
    });
});
```

I am getting following exception.

```
Cannot read property 'applications' of undefined
    at Object.eval [as updateDirectives] (ng:///DynamicTestModule/ApplicationDetailComponent.ngfactory.js:74:33)
    at Object.debugUpdateDirectives [as updateDirectives] (http://localhost:9876/_karma_webpack_/webpack:/node_modules/@angular/core/fesm5/core.js:11054:1)
    at checkAndUpdateView (http://localhost:9876/_karma_webpack_/webpack:/node_modules/@angular/core/fesm5/core.js:10451:1)
    at callViewAction (http://localhost:9876/_karma_webpack_/webpack:/node_modules/@angular/core/fesm5/core.js:10692:1)
    at execComponentViewsAction (http://localhost:9876/_karma_webpack_/webpack:/node_modules/@angular/core/fesm5/core.js:10634:1)
    at checkAndUpdateView (http://localhost:9876/_karma_webpack_/webpack:/node_modules/@angular/core/fesm5/core.js:10457:1)
    at callWithDebugContext (http://localhost:9876/_karma_webpack_/webpack:/node_modules/@angular/core/fesm5/core.js:11344:1)
    at Object.debugCheckAndUpdateView [as checkAndUpdateView] (http://localhost:9876/_karma_webpack_/webpack:/node_modules/@angular/core/fesm5/core.js:11022:1)
    at ViewRef_.push../node_modules/@angular/core/fesm5/core.js.ViewRef_.detectChanges (http://localhost:9876/_karma_webpack_/webpack:/node_modules/@angular/core/fesm5/core.js:8838:1)
    at ComponentFixture.push../node_modules/@angular/core/fesm5/testing.js.ComponentFixture._tick (http://localhost:9876/_karma_webpack_/webpack:/node_modules/@angular/core/fesm5/testing.js:227:1)
```

Comment: What sets the applications property when you use the component in your app? Does the component work in the app? Something in the template is accessing applications and nothing has set it yet, you will see this behaviour outside of testing as well.

Answer (score 0):

The `applications` property on your component needs to be set to something.
This can either be set in the OnInit like the `columnDefinitions` or by setting it on the component instance:

```
component = fixture.componentInstance;
component.applications = [];
fixture.detectChanges();
```